# How to Filter SharePoint Lookup Column using powerapps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a two SharePoint list: List1 and List2
List1 has a Lookup column, its associated with List2.

Ex: List 2 Looks like below

[image]

So in List1 Lookup field I need only Test1 In the Dropdown (Where IsAvailable is No only those values I need in the DD)
How to apply formula for this in Powerapps?

I was trying formula like below:

```
choices(Filter( [@'List1'].LookupField , IsAvailable="No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include second list as a data source in order to achieve this

choices(Filter( [@'List2'], IsAvailable="No"))

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula to filter column based on other column :

Filter(Registrations2,Status.Value = "Active").Event

Source List : Registrations2 
Choice column : Status 
Applyed filter on columnc: Event

Hope this works for you.Following is the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

was able to filter with this :

```
Filter(
    Choices(List1.Field1),
    Id in Filter(
        List2,
        condition on liste 2
    ).ID
)
```